# Как подключиться к интернет используя компьютер подключённый к роутеру (TP-Link) по кабелю и телефон с активной точкой доступа

Tags: сеть, администрирование, ip, wifi

Вопрос, кажется, ламерский, но очень уж интересный.
Есть квартира, в ней роутер (TP-Link), старый десктоп (без Wi-Fi адаптера) и мобила с безлимитным инетом.
Сети нам ещё не преподавали, но интуитивно чую что проблему можно как-то решить. Подскажите куда копать?

Comment: Можно настроить роутер как Repeater, раздавать Wi-Fi с мобильног устройства и по проводу выводить на десктоп.

Comment: Как репитер - настроил. Вот как "по проводу выводить на десктоп" - это интересно.

Comment: Ну как как? Обычно: витой парой от рутера к Вашему ноуту

Comment: Точно не нужно никаких настроек трогать? Просто так, "само" оно не заработало.

Answer (score 1):

Мдя... Значит так: 1. на рутере поднимаем dhcp-сервер - пусть раздает ip в нашей подсети; 2. После того, как соединим его кабелем с ноутом, ноут получит свой адрес и сможет ходить и в интернет и в локаль